# Why does it keep saying unreachable ? Where am I meant to put the assignment statement then?

Tags: java

```
public String toString() {
    return questionText + "\n";
    char label = 'a';
    for(int i= 0; i < answers.length; i++){
        return "("+label+")"+" "+answers[i]+ "\n";
        label++;
    }
}
```

It keeps saying line 4 is unreachable.

Comment: `return` should be the last line of your method as it indicates to exit the method.

Comment: Return statement marks the task of function is done, go back to where it was called from. put anything before return and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Because of return Statement at the very first line.
Once return is called, following lines doesn't matter.

I don't know what questionText is doing, but it may work fine even without the first line itself. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a return statement (question text) immediately after the start. So the char assignment will not run

Answer (score 0):

After the return, you've left the function. Anything below that (within this function) can never execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be with your code, and please dont forget, if answers.length() is just 2 also, it will return only first answer as you are already calling return. I would recommend saving this in list and returning list.

```
  public String toString() { return questionText + "\n"; char label = 'a'; 
        for(int i= 0; i < answers.length; i++){ 
              label++; 
              return "("+label+")"+" "+answers[i]+ "\n"; 
        }
```

With list :

```
public String toString() {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList();
        for(int i= 0; i < answers.length; i++){ 
              arrayList.add(answers);
              label++; 
        }
       return arrayList;
```

I cannot understand your data structure as its written very badly by you. So, I can only help this much.